# How to resample OHLC data with multiple stocks in index?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample, ohlc

I haven't been able to find anything too similar to this I have OHLC data pulled from y-finance for multiple stocks.  This results in a multi-index of columns of OHLC data and stock names

Python Script
'''

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
N_DAYS_AGO = 15
now = datetime.now()
today = datetime(now.year,now.month,now.day, now.hour)
n_days_ago = today - timedelta(days=N_DAYS_AGO)

df = yf.download(['SPY','TLT'],  start=n_days_ago, end=now, interval = "60m")  #no error with 1 stock

ohlc_dict = {
    'Adj Close':'last',
    'Open':'first',
    'High':'max',
    'Low':'min',
    'Close':'last',
    'Volume':'sum'
    }

df_sample = df.resample('W-FRI', closed='left').agg(ohlc_dict)
df_sample  #error with 2 stocks
```

'''

The code above works without a single stock but fails when there are multiple stocks/ multi index columns.

I've tried stacking and unstacking but haven't found a good way to resample this data.  What's the simplest path forward here?